# Access this.$el in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, element, emoji, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a `div` with `contenteditable` for emoji insertion/manipulation and the code I found need the innerText property.

My `editable.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <div
    contenteditable="true"
    @input="update"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        content: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        },
    },
    mounted: () => {
        this.$el.innerText = this.content;
    },
    methods: {
        update (event) {
            this.$emit('update', event.target.innerText);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I'm calling it with `<editable @update="editableRaw = $event"></editable>`

I need a div to include emoji based on svg where the user can type and combine multiple emojis. I'd like to support the entire Unicode 11 sequences.

Hope someone can enlighten me.
Cheers

Comment: you are using an arrow function  for the mounted hook. This causes `this` to not be the vue instance. So replace `mounted: () => {}` with a normal functuin as `mounted: function() {}`

Comment: Wow, now that I know this, it seems very basic :) Thanks!